# Powershell Wait for install to complete using cmd

Tags: powershell, process, cmd, installation

Im running a script that needs to call a setup exe and then another that needs the first to be completed before it can continue, now at the moment due to awkward scenarios, this is accomplished using cmd because i need to add switches and such and variables, like i get i could use start process and then -wait but the process opens seperate msp's and using a cmd is just what ive found works to actually get the setup to run.

So my question how do i get my script to wait for my command to finish and the install to complete before moving on?

I've tried looking around but it doesnt look like anything fits my scenario of using cmd to run these programs.

My current code is...

```
$inslocation = "install\location.exe" 
$insarg = "arguments" 
Start-process $inslocation $insarg -wait
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what are you talking about

Comment: Sorry! originally i was literally using cmd to call the command but i have just answered my own question, i completely had a blonde day!

Comment: scratch that i was getting a bit ahead of myself so at the moment i have

    $inslocation = "install\location.exe"
    $insarg = "arguments"

    Start-process $inslocation $insarg -wait

I have since realised that it starts a setup program and then several other msp files and closes the setup process while these files complete, i need the whole thing to be completed before continuing.

Sorry about the whole confusion again!

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there so it can actually be read in a sensible fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I have a PowerShell module called [SoftwareInstallManager](https://github.com/adbertram/SoftwareInstallManager) that may help. It was designed specifically for what you're working through. It has a child module called Processes that has functions that are used to account for any child processes the parent setup.exe kicks off.

Once imported, you can use it like this:

```
Install-Software -OtherInstallerFilePath 'C:\install\location.exe' -OtherInstallerArgs 'args here'
```

It will kick off the location.exe installer, wait for it and all child processes to finish before releasing control.

Comment: This sounds like something that could work but i've never really installed modules within a script, what would be the best way to do this, this script is going to need to be copied over and ran on an on demand basis so i will have to install it and call it manually each time i run the script rather than deploying it beforehand. Also which files is it that i need for the module, just the softwareinstallmanager.psd1 ? the V2 compat one?

Comment: Nevermind i can just copy it to the module directory and Import it in the script, I'll give it a test but im pretty sure this will work thank you, huge help!

Comment: Awesome! If it does, be sure to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Hi, Sorry about the late response I've only just had time to test this, unfortunately it does not work for me as my program, for example, opens a process named Setup.exe and that then open 2 additional process but closes setup while the 2 process continue running. what ive had to do for now is get the name of the 2 process and just get the id of the process based on name and then ask it to wait-process on that process id, for both process then continue to the next install.

Answer (score 0):

Tiny unclear on your question exactly, but I believe this will get you on the right track.

The easiest way to do this is with Wait-Process.

```
Start-Process "YourProcess"   
Wait-Process -name "YourProcessName" -erroraction SilentlyContinue
...
```

An example using notepad.exe:

```
Start-Process notepad.exe

Wait-Process -Name notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Write-Host "notepad is now closed"
```